# Performance side effects to promoting a Postgres RR to a standalone DB?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgres-11

I promoted a Postgres 11.16 RDS cluster secondary to function as a stand-alone database. This caused a significant decrease in the RR’s performance.  Digging deeper, when comparing the results of running Postgres EXPLAIN on a single production read replica (PROD), and the promoted read replica (RR), there is a 40x decline in performance on the RR.  According to AWS there is no change in the environment so I started looking into what Postres is doing.

Here is a summary of an EXPLAIN query; notice the 40x jump in the Actual Total Time After Startup:

| Database | Estimated Startup Cost (units) | Estimated Total Cost (units) | Actual Startup Time (ms) | Actual Total Time After Startup (ms) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PROD | 329.96 | 29,132.77 | 18.624 | 23.968 |
| RR | 296.49 | 26,883.29 | 28.733 | 974.719 |

Part of the performance loss, about half, goes away after 24 hours.

Are there side effects to promoting a RR to a standalone DB?  I.e., does Postgress need to do additional organization due to the change?

Comment: could you please share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers) for your statement(s) on both servers? (in plain text) And did you run analyze?

Comment: @FrankHeikens Thank you for your comments.  I wasn’t aware of the buffers option for the explain command.  This led me to do a better analysis pointing to a prewarming problem.  

It occurred to me that for our use case, we just want access to a completely stable read-only instance for an hour or two, so it might not be necessary to promote the read replica, which forces a restart.  Do you know if pg_wal_replay_pause() or a similar approach is supported by AWS?

Comment: I'm not familiar wilt pg_wal_replay_pause, but I do know that the extension pg_prewarm is supported by AWS. This could solve your issue